# Copying files based on filename condition

Tags: linux, bash, scp

Copy all files from remote only if filename consists of any name in my file.txt file.

file.txt contains names like

```
rahul
jon
babra
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
while read p; do      
scp -i somefile.pem myuser@myip:myfolder/\*$p\* .
done<file.txt
```

But this would open connection to remote for every name in my file.txt.

I am looking for an optimization to serve all files in a single connection ?

Comment: Check out rsync - it can transfer files over ssh, and the -include-from / --files-from arguments do what it sounds like you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a master connection that each subsequent `scp` can reuse. See the various `Control*` options in `man ssh_config` for advice on using a more secure control path.

```
# Don't run a command (-N), but open a reusable connection (-M and -S)
# then go to the background (-f)
ssh -fNM myuser@myip -S "%C"

while read p; do
  # Reuse the open connection (-S)
  scp -i somefile.pem -S "%C" myuser@myip:myfolder/\*$p\* .
done < file.txt

# Close the background connection
ssh -S "%C" -O exit
```